# How to replace a text with the = sign in vi

Tags: vi

Hi I'm trying to replace all instances of the phrase "type=" for "engine=" on vi. I use

```
:s/type=/engine=/g and also :s/type\=/engine\=/g
```

both giving me "type= or type\= not found". How can i do this on vi?...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

`:%s/type=/engine=/g`

The `%` sign allows you to do the match for every line in file.  Without it, you'd only be trying to match in the line your cursor is on, so it won't find the phrase you're looking for if you're not on the right line.

Answer (score 2):

You' ve forgotten "%" in front of s. Your command will only affect the current text line.
Try

```
:%s/type=/engine=/g
```